# SSIS Derived column - Type casting issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I am very new to SSIS, I have existing SQL table and I want to  load data into decimal(10,2) column, but .csv file as source file contains `--` value in it so that I am trying to replace `--` value to `0.00` using derived column and expression

I have changed the Flat File Source output - Output Column to `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]`

The expression for the new derived column is:

```
[estimated-order-handling-fee-per-order] == "--" ? (DT_DECIMAL,2)"0.00" : (DT_DECIMAL,2)[estimated-order-handling-fee-per-order]
```

Derived Column Output - Columns Output is set to `decimal [DT_DECIMAL]`

SSIS accepts all these, but giving error while running package as below for derived column

> [Derived Column [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed
> because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, and the error row disposition
> on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column
> Output].Columns[estimated-order-handling-fee-per-order-derived]"
> specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object
> of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before
> this with more information about the failure.

Can someone help me with this conversion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error might be caused by empty or null values. Also, try using `DT_NUMERIC` data type instead of `DT_DECIMAL` as following:

```
REPLACE([estimated-order-handling-fee-per-order],"--","") == "" ? (DT_NUMERIC,10,2)"0.00" : (DT_NUMERIC,10,2)[estimated-order-handling-fee-per-order]
```